# Qt statemachine scxml in cmake project without pro file?

Tags: qt, cmake, scxml

I have a large cmake controlled project in which I want a part to use the scxml state machine from qt. My question is the following:

How can i add the scxml module without having a pro file which i understand does not work with cmake?

Something like:

```
QT += scxm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bisides to adding Scxml to `find_package(...)` macro, additional CMake steps are required to integrate Qt SCXML into your application:

```
# Add package
find_package(Qt5 5.10 REQUIRED Core Scxml)

# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(myapp-lib Qt5::Core Qt5::Scxml)

# Process your *.scsml files with Qt SCXML Compiler (qscxmlc)
qt5_add_statecharts(QT_SCXML_COMPILED chart1.scxml chart2.scxml)

# Add to executable
add_executable(myapp main.cpp ${QT_SCXML_COMPILED})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a list of Qt components to load in your CMake, just add `Scxml` to the list.

```
find_package(Qt5 5.9 REQUIRED
             COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Xml Concurrent Scxml
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years too late, but the replies to this question fail to build.

If the compiled SCXML files go through the MOC then the build will throw the following error.

```
(...)
duplicate symbol 'chart1::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' in:
    src/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
    src/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/chart1.cpp.o
(...)
```

To avoid this error, the files generated by `qt5_add_statecharts` need to be explicitly marked as [`SKIP_AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_AUTOMOC.html).

Also, `qt5_add_statecharts` dumps the autogenerated source files in `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, so that path needs to be featured in `target_include_directories` to be reachable.

The example below builds and runs.

```
find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED Core Scxml)

target_link_libraries(myapp-lib 
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Scxml
)

qt5_add_statecharts(QT_SCXML_COMPILED 
    chart1.scxml 
    chart2.scxml
)

set_source_files_properties(${QT_SCXML_COMPILED}
    PROPERTIES
    SKIP_AUTOMOC TRUE
)

add_executable(myapp 
    main.cpp 
    ${QT_SCXML_COMPILED}
)

target_include_directories(myapp
    PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```